# Django silk deadlock (PostgreSQL)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-silk

I am receiving the following error on production server. How can I debug or fix this. I tried searching for answers but nothing makes sense.

```
django: 2.2.3 
django-silk 3.0.0  
postgressql 9.5.14
```

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: deadlock detected DETAIL:  Process
>   11444 waits for ShareLock on transaction 28487795; blocked by process
>   11443. Process 11443 waits for ShareLock on transaction 28487803; blocked by process 11444. HINT:  See server log for query details.
>   CONTEXT:  while deleting tuple (169,20) in relation "silk_response"

Comment: You might find some useful information in the view ```pg_locks``` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/view-pg-locks.html). This may also help: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/explicit-locking.html For further analysis, it would be useful to know what the processes are doing.. As mentioned in the hint, you should find at least the query itself in the server log

Comment: I solved the issue by updating silk dependency to the latest version